# I want to take only alphabets, backspace, delete and space in a text field in java swing platform

Tags: java

Here is my program :

```
private void nametextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)    
{                                    
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();    
        if(!(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||     (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) ||    
                (c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)){  
       getToolkit().beep();  
       evt.consume();  
       }
```

But program doesn't work when i press "SPACE". It returns the if statements, whereas backspace and delete are performed perfectly. So please help with a proper explanation. Thanks for reading....

Comment: You seem to have inverted the `isAlphabetic()` test here

Comment: Wait, do you want to beep if the character entered is _among_ alpha etc or if it is _not_ among them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your logic:

```
if(!(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
    || (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)) {
```

This will beep if the character is either not an alphabetic char, or if it is a backspace, delete or space.

Suggested solution, provided you want to beep if it is not among the above:

```
private void nameTextKeyTyped(final KeyEvent event)
{
    boolean doBeep = true;
    final char c = event.getKeyChar();
    switch (c) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE: 
        case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            doBeep = false;
            break;
        default:
            doBeep = !Character.isAlphabetic(c);
            // no need to "break;": last branch of switch
    }
    if (doBeep)
        getToolkit.beep();
    event.consume();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is on the `(`:

Instead of:

```
if (!(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)){  
    getToolkit().beep();  
    evt.consume();  
 }
```

Change it to: (Look closely at the parenthesis)

```
if (!((Character.isAlphabetic(c)) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE))) {  
    getToolkit().beep();  
    evt.consume();  
 }
```

This `!(Character.isAlphabetic(c))` will return TRUE for space. Note the early `)`!

Comment: Thanks but the previous answer already solved my problem, Thanks for your another way. I am truly honored...